# VBA Checkbox combination enables not right?

Tags: excel, vba

It's probably a very simple mistake what I'm doing but somehow I can't find the solution where it hangs.

So I have 6 checkboxes and 1 label (as a button)

I have a combination:

```vb
Private Sub CheckButtonState()
    If Not (CheckBoxOnlySave.Value Or CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Value Or CheckBoxEditMail.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value) Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

`ElseIf` says, if I check `CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit` and `CheckBoxWithExport`, all checkboxes needs to be `Enabled = False` and `LabelSubmit` enabled = True, but it's strange, `LabelSubmit` stays as False and `CheckBoxSendWithoutExport` stays `Enabled = True`. Why?

Here's a picture of it:

[image: Picture of it]

Whole code, after edited:

```
Private Sub CheckButtonState()
    If CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxEditMail.Value = True And CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxEditMail.Value = True And CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True And CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Not (CheckBoxOnlySave.Value Or CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Value Or CheckBoxEditMail.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value) Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    ElseIf CheckBoxOnlySave.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxEditMail.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    ElseIf CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `ElseIf` comes into play only if the `If` fails. It does not. So `ElseIf` is never checked.

Comment: how could i fix it? I cant say there "And" instead of "or" than it will something else not what i have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `If CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value Then` The if condition checks whether either CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit or CheckBoxWithExport is set to True.
- If you want to check that both CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit and CheckBoxWithExport are True, please change "Or" to "And".

```vb
Private Sub CheckButtonState()
    If CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value And CheckBoxWithExport.Value Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Not (CheckBoxOnlySave.Value Or CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Value Or CheckBoxEditMail.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value) Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Update:

The code is based on following assumption:

- Layer1 Condtions (1~4): two checkboxes combination are enabled
- Layer2 Condtions (5~10): one of 6 checkboxes is enabled
- Layer3 Condtions (11): none of 6 checkboxes is enabled

```vb
Private Sub CheckButtonState()
    If CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True And CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxEditMail.Value = True And CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxEditMail.Value = True And CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True And CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxOnlySave.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxEditMail.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    ElseIf CheckBoxWithExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = True Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Not (CheckBoxOnlySave.Value Or CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Value Or CheckBoxEditMail.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Value Or CheckBoxWithExport.Value Or CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value) Then
        LabelSubmit.Enabled = False
        CheckBoxOnlySave.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSaveAndExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxEditMail.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutEdit.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxWithExport.Enabled = True
        CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

- btw,
  I think that CheckBoxWithExport and CheckBoxSendWithoutExport are mutually exclusive, meaning that users should not select both controls simultaneously. Implementing relevant event code can achieve the mutually exclusive effect. This ensures that the above "If" statement runs according to the intended logic.

```vb
Private Sub CheckBoxWithExport_Change()
    CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value = Not CheckBoxWithExport.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxSendWithoutExport_Change()
    CheckBoxWithExport.Value = Not CheckBoxSendWithoutExport.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked, i changed to "And" cuz i want that both.
Okay i just tried now with my whole code, and it didnt worked, I guess it will very complicated to do this... Just edited my question if you can to check i will be realy happy.

Comment: its 6 checkboxes, so a bit more combination what i want to do :(

Comment: Please share what's the expected output in your post. i think it is doable. The order of If conditions are important . In thoery, 6 checkboxes have 32 (2^6) status combinations. But it doesn't mean you need 32 If clauses.

Comment: I've revised the code based on my undertanding. If it isn't the expected output, pls clarify the biz rules.

Comment: Thank you it worked! just so i understand for the future, it's actually all that matters is the order so that the if and else match and react, right?

Comment: Yes. As soon as any condition in the If/ElseIf clause is met, then execute the code block. The code will jump to the corresponding `End If` statement. That is, the rest If clauses are skipped.